# Line render sometimes doesnt detect intersect and how to make it more forgiving when looping

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a a 2d Line render that creates loops, a Issue I have noticed is that when looping at speed it sometimes doesn't detect, what I want to know is how to stop this from happening, another issue is how to make it more forgiving for example if the line is really close to a previous line I would like it to count that as a loop, and also how would I make the line actually be the mouse pointer instead of having it ghost behind and this might be a issue in the future I currently have it create an area 2d to detect items/objects inside its self I was wondering if there is a better way to accurately detect them inside said loop.

I have a video link I uploaded to show you the issue visually: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jau7YDpZehY

```
extends Node2D

var points_array = PoolVector2Array()
#var check_array = []
var colision_array = []
var index : int = 0
onready var Line = $Line2D
onready var collision = $Area2D/CollisionPolygon2D
onready var collision_area = $Loop_collider

func _physics_process(delta):
    Line.points = points_array # Link the array to the points and polygons
    collision.polygon = points_array
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("left_click"): #This sets a position so that the next line can work together
        points_array.append(get_global_mouse_position()) # This makes a empty vector and the mouse cords is assigned too it
        #points_array.append(Vector2()) #This is the vector that follows the mouse
        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left_click"): #This checks the distance between last vector and the mouse vector
        #points_array[-1] = get_global_mouse_position() # Gets the last position of the array and sets the mouse cords
        var mouse_pos = get_global_mouse_position()
        var distance = 20
        while points_array[-1].distance_to(mouse_pos) > distance:
            var last_point = points_array[-1]
            var cords = last_point + last_point.direction_to(mouse_pos) * distance
            points_array.append(cords)
            create_collision()

    if points_array.size() > 80: # This adds a length to the circle/line so it wont pass 18 mini lines
        points_array.remove(0) #Removes the first array to make it look like it has a length
        #check_array = []
        colision_array[0].queue_free()
        colision_array.remove(0)
    if Input.is_action_just_released("left_click"): # This just clears the screen when the player releases the button
        points_array = PoolVector2Array()
        #check_array = []
        for x in colision_array.size():
            colision_array[0].queue_free()
            colision_array.remove(0)
        #index = 0
    if points_array.size() > 3: # If the loop is long enough, to detect intersects
        if points_array[0].distance_to(get_global_mouse_position()) < 5: # Checks if the end of the loop is near the end, then start new loop
            new_loop()
        for index in range(0, points_array.size() - 3):
            if _segment_collision(
                    points_array[-1],
                    points_array[-2],
                    points_array[index],
                    points_array[index + 1]
                ):
                    new_loop()
                    break
                    
    #if check_array.size() != points_array.size():
    #   check_array = points_array
        #create_collision()

func _segment_collision(a1:Vector2, a2:Vector2, b1:Vector2, b2:Vector2) -> bool:
    # if both ends of segment b are to the same side of segment a, they do not intersect
    if sign(_wedge_product(a2 - a1, b1 - a1)) == sign(_wedge_product(a2 - a1, b2 - a1)):
        return false

    # if both ends of segment a are to the same side of segment b, they do not intersect     
    if sign(_wedge_product(b2 - b1, a1 - b1)) == sign(_wedge_product(b2 - b1, a2 - b1)):
        return false

    # the segments must intersect
    return true

func _wedge_product(a:Vector2, b:Vector2) -> float:
    # this is the length of the cross product
    # it has the same sign as the sin of the angle between the vectors
    return a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x

func new_loop(): # Creates a new loop when holding left click and or loop is complete
    var new_start = points_array[-1]
    collision.polygon = points_array
    points_array = PoolVector2Array()
    collision.polygon = []
    #check_array = []
    points_array.append(new_start)
    for x in colision_array.size():
        colision_array[0].queue_free()
        colision_array.remove(0)

func create_collision(): # Creates collisions to detect when something hits the line renderer
    var new_colision = CollisionShape2D.new()
    var c_shape = RectangleShape2D.new()
    var mid_point = Vector2((points_array[-1].x + points_array[-2].x) / 2,(points_array[-1].y + points_array[-2].y) / 2)
    c_shape.set_extents(Vector2(10,2))
    new_colision.shape = c_shape
    if points_array.size() > 1:
        colision_array.append(new_colision)
        collision_area.add_child(new_colision)
        new_colision.position = mid_point
        #new_colision.position = Vector2((points_array[-1].x),(points_array[-1].y))
        new_colision.look_at(points_array[-2])

func _on_Area2D_area_entered(area): # Test dummies 
    print("detect enemy")


func _on_Loop_collider_area_entered(area):
    print("square detected")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Diagnosis

**Symptom 1**

> I have noticed is that when looping at speed it sometimes doesn't detect

This is what happens:

- When the mouse pointer moved too much between frames, it creates multiple segments, here:

  ```
      var mouse_pos = get_global_mouse_position()
      var distance = 20
      while points_array[-1].distance_to(mouse_pos) > _distance:
          var last_point = points_array[-1]
          var cords = last_point + last_point.direction_to(mouse_pos) * distance
          points_array.append(cords)
          create_collision()
  ```
- But the check for collisions is only comparing the last one, here:

  ```
      for index in range(0, points_array.size() - 3):
          if _segment_collision(
                  points_array[-1],
                  points_array[-2],
                  points_array[index],
                  points_array[index + 1]
              ):
                  new_loop()
                  break
  ```

  *Remember that `[-1]` gives the last item, and `[-2]` gives the second to last.

As a consequence, the intersection can happen on one of the segments that weren't checked.

---

**Symptom 2**

> how to make it more forgiving for example if the line is really close to a previous line I would like it to count that as a loop

We could check distance from point to segment.

---

**Symptom 3**

> how would I make the line actually be the mouse pointer instead of having it ghost behind

Currently the segments are all of the same length. This seems to be a limitation of the way you create `CollisionShape2D`.

---

### Treatment selection

We could address Symptom 1 by checking every segment. Symptom 2 by improving said checking. But we would still need a solution for Symptom 3 that allows variable segment lengths.

If we create a solution that supports variable segment lengths, we would not need to create multiple segments at once, which solves Symptom 1. We would still need to improve the checking to solve Symptom 2.

If we need to improve the way we check collisions and we are rewriting the collisions anyway, we might as well implement something that allows us to detect self intersections.

We are going to transplant a new way to define collision shapes which allows us to make rotated rectangles of the dimensions we want.

---

### Surgery

I ended up rewriting the whole script. *Because I'm like that, I guess.*

I decided to have the script create its child nodes in the following structure:

```
Node
├_line
├_segments
└_loops
```

Here`_line` will be a `Line2D`, `_segments` will hold multiple `Area2D`, each a segment. And `_loops` will also hold `Area2D`, but they are the polygons of the loops traced.

This will be done in `_ready`:

```
var _line:Line2D
var _segments:Node2D
var _loops:Node2D

func _ready() -> void:
    _line = Line2D.new()
    _line.name = "_line"
    add_child(_line)
    _segments = Node2D.new()
    _segments.name = "_segments"
    add_child(_segments)
    _loops = Node2D.new()
    _loops.name = "_loops"
    add_child(_loops)
```

---

Another decision I took was to consider the way of the data on the application: We are taking positions. The first position is when the click is just pressed. Subsequent positions are when it moves. From those positions we take points to add to both the line and the segments. From the segments we will get the loops. And we will continue in this manner until the click is released.

Well, if whether or not click was just pressed or it is held, it does not matter. Either way, we take the position of the mouse.

Now, `_physics_process` will look like this:

```
func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left_click"):
        position(get_global_mouse_position())
    # TODO
```

We also need to handle when the click is released. Let us make a function for that and worry later about it:

```
func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if Input.is_action_pressed("left_click"):
        position(get_global_mouse_position())
    if Input.is_action_just_released("left_click"):
        total_purge()
```

On `position` we will follow that odd trick of moving the last point to match the most recent position. We need to make sure that there are at least two points. So the first point does not move, and we can safely move the last point.

```
var _points:PoolVector2Array = PoolVector2Array()
var _max_distance = 20

func position(pos:Vector2) -> void:
    var point_count = _points.size()
    if point_count == 0:
        _points.append(pos)
        _points.append(pos)
    elif  point_count == 1:
        _points.append(pos)
    else:
        if _points[-2].distance_to(pos) > _max_distance:
            _points.append(pos)
        else:
            _points[-1] = pos
```

Notice we check the distance to the second to last point. We cannot check against the last point because that is the one we are moving.

If the distance is greater than `_max_dinstance` then we add a new point, otherwise we move the last point.

We also need to add and update segments:

```
var _points:PoolVector2Array = PoolVector2Array()
var _max_distance = 20

func position(pos:Vector2) -> void:
    var point_count = _points.size()
    if point_count == 0:
        _points.append(pos)
        _points.append(pos)
        add_segment(pos, pos)
    elif  point_count == 1:
        _points.append(pos)
        add_segment(_points[-2], pos)
    else:
        if _points[-2].distance_to(pos) > _max_distance:
            _points.append(pos)
            add_segment(_points[-2], pos)
        else:
            _points[-1] = pos
            change_segment(_points[-2], pos)
```

You know, we worry later about how that works.

We also need to handle the case when there are too many points:

```
var _points:PoolVector2Array = PoolVector2Array()
var _max_points = 30
var _max_distance = 20

func position(pos:Vector2) -> void:
    var point_count = _points.size()
    if point_count == 0:
        _points.append(pos)
        _points.append(pos)
        add_segment(pos, pos)
    elif point_count == 1:
        _points.append(pos)
        add_segment(_points[-2], pos)
    elif point_count > _max_points:
        purge(point_count - _max_points)
    else:
        if _points[-2].distance_to(pos) > _max_distance:
            _points.append(pos)
            add_segment(_points[-2], pos)
        else:
            _points[-1] = pos
            change_segment(_points[-2], pos)
```

We need to update the `Line2D`, and we need to handle any loops:

```
var _points:PoolVector2Array = PoolVector2Array()
var _max_points = 30
var _max_distance = 20

func position(pos:Vector2) -> void:
    var point_count = _points.size()
    if point_count == 0:
        _points.append(pos)
        _points.append(pos)
        add_segment(pos, pos)
    elif point_count == 1:
        _points.append(pos)
        add_segment(_points[-2], pos)
    elif point_count > _max_points:
        purge(point_count - _max_points)
    else:
        if _points[-2].distance_to(pos) > _max_distance:
            _points.append(pos)
            add_segment(_points[-2], pos)
        else:
            _points[-1] = pos
            change_segment(_points[-2], pos)

    _line.points = _points
    process_loop()
```

Alright, let us talk about adding and updating segments:

```
var _width = 5

func add_segment(start:Vector2, end:Vector2) -> void:
    var points = rotated_rectangle_points(start, end, _width)
    var segment = Area2D.new()
    var collision = create_collision_polygon(points)
    segment.add_child(collision)
    _segments.add_child(segment)

func change_segment(start:Vector2, end:Vector2) -> void:
    var points = rotated_rectangle_points(start, end, _width)
    var segment = (_segments.get_child(_segments.get_child_count() - 1) as Area2D)
    var collision = (segment.get_child(0) as CollisionPolygon2D)
    collision.set_polygon(points)
```

Here `_width` is the width of the collision polygons we want.

We are either adding an `Area2D` with a collision polygon (created via function we will worry about later), or we are taking the last `Area2D` and updating its collision polygon by the same means.

So, how do we get the points for the rotated rectangle?

```
static func rotated_rectangle_points(start:Vector2, end:Vector2, width:float) -> Array:
    var diff = end - start
    var normal = diff.rotated(TAU/4).normalized()
    var offset = normal * width * 0.5
    return [start + offset, start - offset, end - offset, end + offset]
```

So you take the vector that goes from the start to the end of the segment, and rotate it a quarter turn (a.k.a. 90º). That gives you a vector that is normal (perpendicular) to the segment, which we will use to give it width.

From the starting point, we find the first point of the rectangle by going half width in the normal direction, and we find the second by going the other half width in the opposite direction. Do the same with the ending point and we have the four corners of the rectangle.

And we return them in an order such that they go around the rectangle.

Creating a collision polygon with those points is straight forward:

```
static func create_collision_polygon(points:Array) -> CollisionPolygon2D:
    var result = CollisionPolygon2D.new()
    result.set_polygon(points)
    return result
```

---

Ok, let us talk about purging. I added a function to purge points (of the line) and segments. That is part of the total purge. The other part will be removing the loops:

```
func total_purge():
    purge(_points.size())
    purge_loops()
```

*That was easy.*

Alright, to purge points and segment we iterate and remove them.

```
func purge(index:int) -> void:
    var segments = _segments.get_children()
    for _index in range(0, index):
        _points.remove(0)
        if segments.size() > 0:
            _segments.remove_child(segments[0])
            segments[0].queue_free()
            segments.remove(0)

    _line.points = _points
```

That check for `if segments.size() > 0` is necessary, by the way. Sometimes the purge leaves points without segment, which cause problems later. And this is the simpler solution.

*And, of course, we have to update the `Line2D`.*

What about purging loops? Well, you remove them all:

```
func purge_loops() -> void:
    for loop in _loops.get_children():
        if is_instance_valid(loop):
            loop.queue_free()
```

---

Finally we can process the loops. We will be checking the overlapping areas of the segments to find if they intersect with each other.

One caveat: we want to ignore overlaps of adjacent segments (which are bound to happen, and do not constitute loops).

So we iterate over the segments, check the overlapping areas, look for them among the segments (if they are there at all), and if they are not adjacent (the different of their index among the segments must be greater than 1). If all that happens, we have a loop:

```
func process_loop() -> void:
    var segments = _segments.get_children()
    for index in range(segments.size() - 1, 0, -1):
        var segment = segments[index]
        var candidates = segment.get_overlapping_areas()
        for candidate in candidates:
            var candidate_index = segments.find(candidate)
            if candidate_index == -1:
                continue

            if abs(candidate_index - index) > 1:
                push_loop(candidate_index, index)
                purge(index)
                return
```

So, when a loops happens we want to do something with it, right? That is what `push_loop` is for. We also want to remove the points and segments that were part of the loop (or were before the loop), so we call `purge`.

Only `push_loop` is left to discuss:

```
func push_loop(first_index:int, second_index:int) -> void:
    purge_loops()
    var loop = Area2D.new()
    var points = _points
    points.resize(second_index)
    for point_index in first_index + 1:
        points.remove(0)

    var collision = create_collision_polygon(points)
    loop.add_child(collision)
    _loops.add_child(loop)
```

As you can see, it creates an `Area2D`, with a collision polygon that corresponds to the loop. *I decide to use `rezise` to remove points that are after the loop, and a for loop to remove the points that are before. So only the points of the loop remain.*

Also notice I'm calling `purge_loops` at the start, that ensures there will only be one loop at a time.

---

Going back to the symptoms: Symptoms 1 and 3 are solved by that trick of always moving the last point (and updating the segment). And Symptom 2 is addressed by the width of the rectangles. Tweak that value.

Comment: I read through it all, and its amazing I love learning how you do things it makes sense and you explanations are great, thanks for this script!